# Not able to see analytics of Android in Flurry

Tags: android, flurry

In my android applcation I am calling FlurryAgent.onStartSession in onStart method. And FlurryAgent.onEvent("Started game");  subsequently. But still I am not able to see any data on the flurry dash board.

I am running this application only on emulator.

Is there any other way of doing this?

Comment: me to. what is the solution? @Android_IT do you solve the issue?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Are you sure you have the correct id?

Flurry isn't really real time, you have to wait a bit. Have you done that?

Comment: Yes I have taken the Id generated from the Flurry site. Still there are no analytics displayed. I am running the application on the emulator. It wouldnt cause any problem right....

Comment: Just ensure that you have the internet permission. I dont think so. You could always check the logcat since flurry outputs some information in the logcat.

Comment: In logcat I see that information is being sent to the Flurry.. But not knowing is it reaching Flurry as nothing is being updated on the dash board.

Comment: Well, as I said. It will not be real time. You will probably have to wait a couple of hours before you can see the information. Have you done that?

Comment: No I will wait and see now. As of now I can see in the Log cat the messages from Flurry as "Report Successful", "Processing report response" and "Done sending initial agent report"

Comment: Thanks David. It works now. I am able to see the analytics. Thanks everyone for the help.

Comment: I have the same problem, but can't see any thing on log cat that if data send to flurry or not?